# How to pre-load Core Data with a SQLite file that have references to images that were saved using "external storage"?

Tags: swift, iphone, sqlite, core-data, persistence

My goal is pre-loading Core Data, at the first app launch. So far I ran a simulation and filled Core Data with data. (I had checked "allow external Storage").

I went into application_support and copied: MyApp.sqlite-wal, MyApp.sqlite-shm, .MyApp_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/ and MyApp.sqlite.

Then I added the MyApp.sqlite file in my app bundle and added this code in my app delegate:

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let modelName = "MyApp"

        var container: NSPersistentContainer!

        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName)
        
        
        // Preloading
        let appName: String = "MyApp"
        var persistentStoreDescriptions: NSPersistentStoreDescription

        let storeUrl = self.getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite")

        if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: (storeUrl.path)) {
            let seededDataUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: appName, withExtension: "sqlite")
            try! FileManager.default.copyItem(at: seededDataUrl!, to: storeUrl)
        }

        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        description.url = storeUrl

        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        //End Preloading

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {

                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

It works but It looks like it doesn't find the images that were saved in external storage. They're present in .MyApp_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA as references.
Where should I add the references?

Load everything is my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Create "MyAppSeedData" dir and paste MyApp.sqlite, the MyApp_SUPPORT, the MyApp.sqilte-smh, MyApp.sqilte-wal files inside.

Step 2: Drag MyAppSeedData to the bundle under AppDelegate and tick the box add target.

Step 3: These functions must be in AppDelegate file:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
{
    //If first launch condition == true {
    seedData()
    //}
    return true
}

    
func seedData() {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    
    //Destination URL: Application Folder
    let libURL = fm.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let destFolder = libURL.appendingPathComponent("Application Support").path
    //Or
    //let l1 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.applicationSupportDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).last!
    //
    
    //Starting URL: MyAppSeedData dir
    let folderPath = Bundle.main.resourceURL!.appendingPathComponent("MyAppSeedData").path
    
    let fileManager = FileManager.default
        let urls = fileManager.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        if let applicationSupportURL = urls.last {
            do{
                try fileManager.createDirectory(at: applicationSupportURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            }
            catch{
                print(error)
            }
        }
    copyFiles(pathFromBundle: folderPath, pathDestDocs: destFolder)
}


func copyFiles(pathFromBundle : String, pathDestDocs: String) {
    let fm = FileManager.default
    do {
        let filelist = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: pathFromBundle)
        let fileDestList = try fm.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: pathDestDocs)

        for filename in fileDestList {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: "\(pathDestDocs)/\(filename)")
        }
        
        for filename in filelist {
            try? fm.copyItem(atPath: "\(pathFromBundle)/\(filename)", toPath: "\(pathDestDocs)/\(filename)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error info: \(error)")
    }
}




// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let modelName = "MyApp"

    var container: NSPersistentContainer!

    container = NSPersistentContainer(name: modelName)
            
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file named `MyApp.sqlite` with external binary storage in some directory (here, the app bundle), Core Data puts those files in a sub-directory named `.MyApp_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/`. You need to recursively copy that directory and everything in its sub-directories.

Using that path is not a good idea, though, because it's undocumented and could change without warning. Also, this will miss `MyApp.sqlite-wal` and `MyApp.sqlite-shm`, if they exist.

A better idea is to put the seed store in a custom directory of its own, and copy everything from *that* directory. Instead of just having `MyApp.sqlite`, you'd have a directory named `MyAppSeedData` which would contain `MyApp.sqlite`. It would also contain all the other stuff Core Data needs like the external binary files. Use the same `FileManager` function to copy the `MyAppSeedData` directory (because it will recursively copy every file) and you should be fine.

The code to copy the folder would be something like this:

```
if let sourceDirURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Source Folder", withExtension: nil) {
    let destinationDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("TestFolder")
    if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: destinationDirURL.path) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceDirURL, to: destinationDirURL)
        } catch {
            print("Error copying directory: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

You could then add the SQLite file name to the end of `destinationDirURL` and use it for Core Data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so currently I have MyApp.sqlite-wal, MyApp.sqlite-shm, .MyApp_SUPPORT/_EXTERNAL_DATA/ and MyApp.sqlite. I copied those files from application_support of a previous build. I pasted all those in MyAppSeedData folder and I ve dragged it in the bundle in Xcode under AppDelegate. Then I modified .appendingPathComponent("MyApp.sqlite") and let seededDataUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "PackTagsSeedData", withExtension: nil) but I got a fatal error: “MyAppSeedData” couldn’t be opened.". I don't know if I have done the right thing?

Comment: It sounds correct, and in a quick test here, it seems to work. When you dragged the folder into Xcode, did you add it to the app's target? You can check on that in the file inspector on the right side of the Xcode window, under "target membership". When you select the folder on the left side of the window, the app target should be checked on the right.

Comment: Yes MyAppSeedData folder is added to the app target.

Comment: I added some code in case that helps. If not, I have no idea what the problem is. Copying a persistent store like this and using it absolutely should work. If it doesn't, I don't have enough information about your code to say why.

Comment: I made it work, Core Data usually stores the .sqlite and external references in a "Application Support" directory located in Library directory, so what I did is I made a folder "MyAppSeedData", pasted the .sqlite, the _SUPPORT, the -smh, -wal files inside, brought it to the bundle. In Appdelegate I added code to create an "Application Support" dir as it doesn't exist yet at first launch and code to copy all content from the dir in the bundle to that just created dir. This way the app find a pre-populated data base and all the files where they're supposed to be. I posted the code I used.